# how can i fix this download chromium prob

Tags: python, chromium, gn

i try to downwload chromium code .
i'm currently at the command
$ gn gen out/Default
but its show me this error :

```
C:\Users\sapir\Downloads\depot_tools\chromium\src>gn gen out/Default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 577, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 573, in main
    return commands[sys.argv[1]](*sys.argv[2:])
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 388, in CopyDlls
    _CopyDebugger(target_dir, target_cpu)
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 424, in _CopyDebugger
    (debug_file, full_path))
Exception: dbghelp.dll not found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll"
You must installWindows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 including the "Debugging Tools for Windows" feature.
**ERROR** at //build/toolchain/win/BUILD.gn:49:3: Script returned non-zero exit code.
  exec_script("../../vs_toolchain.py",
  ^----------
Current dir: C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default/
Command: C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin/python/bin/python.exe C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py copy_dlls C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default Debug x64
Returned 1 and printed out:

Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp140.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\msvcp140.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vccorlib140.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vccorlib140.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vcruntime140.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vcruntime140.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vcruntime140_1.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vcruntime140_1.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\ucrtbase.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp140d.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\msvcp140d.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vccorlib140d.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vccorlib140d.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vcruntime140d.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vcruntime140d.dll...
Copying C:\WINDOWS\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\vcruntime140_1d.dll...
Copying C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\ucrt\ucrtbased.dll to C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/out/Default\ucrtbased.dll...

See //BUILD.gn:66:1: which caused the file to be included.
group("gn_all") {
^----------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py", line 304, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py", line 257, in main
    vc_lib_um_path = FindFileInEnvList(env, 'LIB', ';', 'user32.lib')
  File "C:/Users/sapir/Downloads/depot_tools/chromium/src/build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py", line 211, in FindFileInEnvList
    file_name, env_name, '\n'.join(parts))
AssertionError: user32.lib is not found in LIB:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\lib\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64
Check if it is installed.
```

what i need to do ??

Comment: The tags are for questions about code in the respective langague. I don't know where your question fits, but it isnt a question about python,c or c++ code

Comment: If the content of `vs_toolchain.py` is relevant, you should show it.

Comment: @Booboo Actually that file is part of the Chromium build system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed the debugging tools for Windows. It's quiet clear from this message

```
You must install Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 including the "Debugging Tools for Windows"
```

because the `GN` build system is searching for those files when generating build files when executing the command `gn gen out\YourBuildFolder`. You should install `Debugging Tools for Windows` and looks like the Chromium version that you are using requires Windows 10 SDK version `10.0.19041.0`.